# Why is my Razor controller action call not working when called via Ajax in a Javascript function?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I have an Asp.NetCore Razor application.
I am attempting to call into my controller via $ajax() to invoke a contoller action.
The action is not getting in my controller.
I feel like there is an issue with the way my @Url.Action() in the javascript function is configured.
It should be of the form @Url.Action(ActionName, Controller).

I'm not seeing any errors in the devtools window console.
What am I doing wrong here?

**Here is a C# code snippet containing my DeleteCompany action on the controller:**

```
public class CompanyController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCompany(Guid companyId)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**Here is my html snippet where the ConfirmDelete() function gets invoked:**

```
<text>
    <input type="hidden" value="<%- data.CompanyId %>" name="CompanyId" />
    <input type="image" value="<%- data.CompanyId %>" src="/icon/close.png" width="25" height="25" 
           onclick="ConfirmDelete('<%- data.CompanyId %>', '<%- data.CompanyName %>')"/>
</text>
```

**Here is my javascript to prompt for confirmation and make ajax call to controller:**

```
<script>
function ConfirmDelete(companyId, companyName) {
    var message = "<i>Are you sure you want to delete Customer: ".concat(companyName).concat("?");
    var result = DevExpress.ui.dialog.confirm(message, "Confirm Company Delete");
    result.done(function (dialogResult) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("DeleteCompany","Company")',
          data: { companyId: companyId },
          success: function(data) {
            //call is successfully completed and we got result in data
          },
          error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                          //some errror, some show err msg to user and log the error
                          alert(xhr.responseText);
          }
        });
    });
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should add `type:"Post"` in your ajax,then ajax does not support redirection, you should redirect in the success function of Ajax.

You can change your code like below.

```
 $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("DeleteCompany","Company")',
      data: { companyId: companyId },
      type:"Post",
      success: function() {
       location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Company")'
      },
      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                      //some errror, some show err msg to user and log the error
                      alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
```

Then in your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCompany(Guid companyId)
{
    // Do some stuff
     return Ok();
}
```